# Multiple tests with YepNope.js?

Tags: javascript, yepnope

I'm using [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/) to load scripts conditionally based on tests (duh) but I'm having a problem in that I want to test multiple conditions, and load multiple polyfills based on said results.

So for example, something like:

```
 yepnope([{
     test: test1 || test2,
     nope: ['poly1.js', 'poly2.js'],
     load: ['default.js']
}]);
```

Unfortunately though, an end user might only need poly1 and not poly2, in the above both are loaded even if only one test is failed.

I guess what I'm asking is is there a way of loading only needed scripts with yepnope, without crazy nesting/using the complete function a lot? As opposed to loading multiple scripts even if only one test fails.

Answer (score 0):

Just duplicate the whole thing with the other feature test, example:

```
yepnope({
    test: Modernizr.csstransitions,
    yep: 'transitions_js.js',
    nope: 'no_transitions_js.js'
});
yepnope({
    test: Modernizr.svg,
    nope: 'no_svg.css'
});
```

Hopefully it's not too late to answer the question :)